# First Visual Force Page Help - Rendered fields

Tags: visualforce, rendered

This my first attempt at creating a VF page using rendered fields.

I have a Pick list called " Product Type" Pick list values are : Chem-protection , Hand protection

If chem-protection is chosen i want the text field called "Product Code" to appear

If Hand protection is chosen i want the text field "Size"to appear.

The code i have created already is :

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Costing Enquiry Form Edit" mode="detail">
         <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Customer_Name__c}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.OwnerId}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Contact_Name__c}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Target_Selling_Price__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.End_User__c}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Estimated_Quantity__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Status__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Sample_Required__c}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Quote_Number__c}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Customer_is_currently_using_Seen__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Product_Type__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Required_Standards_CE_Markings__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Special_Requirements_Comments__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Send_to__c}" required="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>            

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

<apex:relatedList list="OpenActivities" />
<apex:relatedList list="ActivityHistories" />
<apex:relatedList list="CombinedAttachments" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to add an actionSupport on the source picklist, and then conditionally render the other values:

```
<apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="false">
  <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Product_Type__c}" required="true">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" />
  </apex:inputField>
<apex:actionRegion>
<apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Product_Code__c}" rendered="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Product_Type__c='chem-protection'}" required="true" />
<apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Size__c}" rendered="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Product_Type__c='hand protection'}" required="true" />
```

Adjust as you'd like.